# With Spring 4.2 how can i make the path variable as optional

Tags: java, spring

```
@RequestMapping(value="/return/{name}",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<String> ReturnName(HttpServletRequest req,@PathVariable(name) String inputName) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(inputName, HttpStatus.OK)
}
```

I have found the solution like

```
@RequestMapping(value="/return/{name}",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<String> ReturnName(HttpServletRequest req,@PathVariable(name) Optional<String> inputName) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(inputName.isPresent() ? inputName.get() : null, HttpStatus.OK)
}
```

But it is not working as expected.

It throws 405 if the value for name is not give.

Example :

return/ram is working fine.

return throws 405 error.

Whether i am missing anything?

Is there any spring property to handle this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make your own proposed solution work and use a single method, you can use like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value= {"/return/{name}", "/return"},method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<String> ReturnName(HttpServletRequest req, @PathVariable("name") Optional<String> inputName) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(inputName.isPresent() ? inputName.get() : null, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

In the end it is still 2 endpoints like Baldurian proposed.

Answer (score 3):

You can't, simply create another method to catch the url without the {name} in the URL.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/return",method=RequestMethod.GET)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@RequestMapping(value= {"/return/{name}", "/return"},method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<String> ReturnName(HttpServletRequest req, @PathVariable("name") Optional<String> inputName) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(inputName.isPresent() ? inputName.get() : null, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```